# PyQt: why sendind PATCH request with JSON data returns null-string?

Tags: python, json, qt, rest, pyqt

I sending a PATCH request using this code:

```
self.sendurl = QtCore.QUrl("http://"+ server + ":" + port + "/path/" + str(i['id']))
self.rdata = {'status': 'online'}
self.rdata = json.dumps(self.rdata)

self.request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest()
self.manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
self.request.setUrl(self.sendurl)
self.request.setHeader(0, 'application/json')
self.rdata = bytes(self.rdata, 'UTF-8')
self.data = QtCore.QByteArray(self.rdata)

self.buffer = QtCore.QBuffer()

self.buffer.open(QtCore.QBuffer.ReadWrite)
self.buffer.writeData(self.data)
self.buffer.seek(0)

self.patchbytes = bytes('PATCH', 'UTF-8')
self.patchverb = QtCore.QByteArray(self.patchbytes)
self.response = QtCore.QByteArray()
self.response = self.manager.sendCustomRequest(self.request, self.patchverb, self.buffer)


self.response = self.response.readAll().data().decode('utf-8')
self.response = str(self.response)
print(self.response)
self.response = json.loads(self.response)
```

Normal response contain JSON object like this: `{'status':'online', 'request':'ok'}`. But I get this:

[image]

I think I'm just sending an incorrect request, but I do not understand what's wrong with it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: try with: `self.response = bytearray(self.response.readAll().data()).decode(); self.response = json.loads(self.response)`

Comment: 'bytearray()' method is equivalent to 'data()', it's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer to my question. I just need to wait for the request to complete.

After this line

```
self.response = self.manager.sendCustomRequest(self.request, self.patchverb, self.buffer)
```

there should be this code:

```
self.loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
self.manager.finished.connect(self.loop.exit)
self.loop.exec()
```